# Can OS X access files in my Dropbox account without using space on my local hard drive?

Tags: macos, dropbox

Question in title. Is there any way for such configuration?
OR at least that files are stored only on one computer.
Of course I am aware that I can use internet browser version of dropbox, but I would like to use the desktop one, but exactly in the way a browser version works, i.e. without losing hard drive space.

Comment: If you use the Chrome web browser you can use a Chrome app: [Dropbox for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dropbox/ioekoebejdcmnlefjiknokhhafglcjdl?hl=en-US). Then there's also the option to selectively sync folders under *Dropbox Preferences > Advanced*. However, if you do not sync the folders to your Mac, you will not be able to browse them locally. Therefore, you'd end up using the menu icon to access the web interface without a password. Finally, if you do not want to sync Dropbox locally you must use *some* kind of web interface! What's better than a web browser?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> **Update**: See nassimhddd's [answer below](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/119316/14994) about [ExpanDrive](https://www.expandrive.com/) allowing you to mount your DropBox account as (external) drive - since
>   its Mac version 3.0.3021 [May 2013](http://updates.expandrive.com/release_notes/expandrive).

The short answer to this is: No. As far as I'm aware, you can't mount your Dropbox account as some sort of remote file share - its synced files are always written to your local disk.

That said, you *can* change the location of the Dropbox folder away from its default of `~/Dropbox`, so if you have a separate internal or external disk you could put the Dropbox folder there.

You may encounter problems if Dropbox occasionally can't access the detached volume holding its folder, however. See [here](https://www.dropbox.com/help/89/en):

> Your Dropbox folder must be available when your computer boots and
>   before the Dropbox desktop application starts. Some USB drives, for
>   example, take some time to mount before your computer recognizes them.
>   The Dropbox desktop application could start before such a drive is
>   ready and get confused. You will receive an error and Dropbox will
>   give you the opportunity to relink your Dropbox account or exit if it
>   is unable to find your Dropbox folder.

Answer (score 7):

## [ExpanDrive](http://www.expandrive.com/expandrive)

Since its Mac version 3.0.3021, [ExpanDrive](http://www.expandrive.com/expandrive) makes this possible. I just tested it and am very satisfied: very easy to setup and the folder navigation is very reactive (which was not the case with DropDAV). Plus it works with many other services (google drive, box, etc.).

Answer (score 3):

You can use a third party service like [Otixo](http://otixo.com) or [DropDAV](http://dropdav.com) that will allow you to connect through webdav protocol.
Unfortunately I don't know anything free.

Anyway after you have create your account you have just to press cmd+k in the finder and connect to the server using the new credentials. This will mount a virtual drive with Dropbox content. You can also mount the drive at startup adding it into login items list.

Answer (score 0):

rclone mount allows Linux, FreeBSD, macOS and Windows to mount any of Rclone’s cloud storage systems as a file system with FUSE.

[rclone mount](https://rclone.org/commands/rclone_mount/)

Comment: This does not appear to be an answer to the question in OP which is asking for a solution within Dropbox. Pls explain how your answer relates to Dropbox or modify it.

Answer (score 0):

[Transmit](https://panic.com/transmit/) can access your Dropbox files without needing the Dropbox app.

Answer (score 0):

For basic free Dropbox no but see other answers for workarounds

For paid versions of Dropbox there is something called Smart Sync https://www.dropbox.com/smart-sync which allows you to choose if certain files are downloaded to a device or not.

> Normally, synced files are downloaded fully to your computer and they take up hard drive space. With Smart Sync, you can make files and folders "online only". Online-only files only use a small amount of hard drive space to store information such as the file name, size and thumbnail, but the full contents of the files are stored securely in the Dropbox cloud. You’ll always see your online-only files on your computer, so when you need them, you can open them with just a click.

Answer (score -2):

Here is the solution. Dropbox is great! Selective syncing. 
https://www.dropbox.com/guide/business/manage-files/save-your-hard-drive-space

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. However, please summarize data outside StackExchange and quote them here, as the link could die, and nobody could learn from your answer

Answer (score -3):

This is a little bit old question, but yes, this can be done very easily.

[ExpanDrive](http://www.expandrive.com/) is an app that does that. It works not only for Dropbox but also for Google Drive, S3, SFTP WebDAV and many other cloud storage solutions.

Comment: This answer has already been given. If you wanted to correct, update it or add to it, please edit the existing answer.